# Can I know the extending class from the super class in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following classes.

```
public class Super{

  public static void useSubClass(){
     //I want to access the sub class object here, how.
  }
}

public class Sub1 extends Super{

}

public class Sub2 extends Super{

}
```

I want to access the sub-class object from a static method in super-class. i.e. When I call `Sub1.useSubClass()` the method has access to `Sub1.class` and when I use `Sub2.useSubClass()`, I can access the `Sub2.class`.

Is there any way to access the sub-class object from super-class.

Comment: There is no instance at all when calling a static method. Your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The superclass has no knowledge of the classes extending it.

Comment: Why just not call, Sub1.getClass(); ?

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. I was suspecting the same. I was just trying to implement a super ActiveRecord-like class like that in rails. Thought, to ask if there might exist some stuff in reflection or something that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured something out. It works if implemented with care.

```
/** SuperClass.java **/
public abstract class SuperClass {

    public static void printClass(){
    System.out.println(new ImplementingClassRetriever().getCallingClass());
    }

    static class ImplementingClassRetriever extends SecurityManager{
    public Class getCallingClass() {
        Class[] classes = getClassContext();
        for (Class clazz : classes) {
        if (SuperClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) && clazz != null
            && !clazz.equals(SuperClass.class)) {
            return clazz;
        }
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
}


/** Main.java **/
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sub.printClass(); //this does not work
    Sub.testStaticCall(); //this works!! :)
    }
}


class Sub extends SuperClass{

    public static void testStaticCall(){
    Sub.printClass(); //calling the method in the super class
    }
}
```

This is just a toy example. The super class contains a static class that contains a method to retrieve the calling class.

In the subclass I have another static method which calls the superclass's method for printing the class name.

The `Main` class/function contains two calls to `Sub`'s inherited and locally implemented method. The first call prints null, because the calling context (i.e. Main) is not a subclass of `Super` However the delegate method in `Sub` works because the calling context is now a subclass of `SuperClass` and hence the calling class can be determined.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you cannot do that from a superclass (and shouldn't!) because you won't know (and shouldn't assume anything about!) what classes will inherit from your superclass.

Depending on exactly what you want to do, there are alternatives, such as:

- Use the [template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) to define "filler methods" that your subclasses must implement; these filler methods will be called by the template method in your superclass.
- Define methods to be overridden by your subclass.
- Define interfaces to be implemented by your subclass.

---

**Update:** As @JB Nizet has pointed out, I might have misread the question.

Here's something (very similar to the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)) you can do if you wish to access subclasses from the static method in your superclass:

- Define a static listener list in your superclass, call it `List observerList`
- In the constructor of your superclass, add the class instance itself to that static `observerList`
- For all subclasses, it is their responsibility to call `super()` from their constructors in order to register themselves to `observerList` (and unregister in deconstructor)
- Then in your superclass's static `useSubClass()` method, you can iterate through that list of subclass instances, find the particular one you care about (maybe specified by some argument), and then do something with it.

Comment: I think you misread the question. The OP doesn't call an instance method, but a static method.

Comment: I don't see how your update would allow to identify Sub2.class when the code calls `Sub2.useSubclass()`, especially if no instance of any of the classes has ever been constructed. If an argument must be passed to the method, then just call `Sub2.useSubclass(Sub2.class)`, and the solution is to just use the provided argument. No need for all this broken visitor stuff.

Comment: @JBNizet updated my answer with a bit about using an observer list, still seems a bit hacky though.

Comment: It's not only hacky, but completely broken and unnecessary. Read my previous comment.

Answer (score 4):

Static methods are not inherited, and calling `Sub2.useSubClass()` is strictly equivalent to calling `Super.useSubclass()`.

There is no way to get this information, because it doesn't exist. The compiler allows calling `Sub2.useSubclass()`, but translates it into `Super.useSubclass()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void useSubClass(Super sub) {
    if (sub instanceof Sub1) {
        // Do something
    } else if (sub instanceof Sub2) {
        // Do something else
    } else {
        // Something else is extending Super
    }
}
```

However, a better question is why? Can't you simply override the method in your subclass?

Comment: Static methods are not overridden

Comment: Why does the method have the be static?

Comment: what do you mean "why". That is the requirement. The method is called on the class and hence they need to be static.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot because the super-class cannot know the methods of the sub-classes.
You should consider to create a new class which sees both super-class and sub-classes and implement the static method inside this new class

Answer (score 0):

For the record, you could do this in Python, using class methods:

```
class super(object):
    @classmethod
    def usesubclass(cls):
        print cls

class sub1(super):
    pass

class sub2(super):
    pass
```

Using this code, you could call `sub1.usesubclass()` or `sub2.usesubclass()`, and that would print the representations of the `sub1` and `sub2` classes, respectively:

```
>>> sub1.usesubclass()
<class '__main__.sub1'>
>>> sub2.usesubclass()
<class '__main__.sub2'>
```

Java, however, does not support such mechanisms, unfortunately. When you compile `Sub1.useSubClass()` in your example, the compiler will simply use `Sub1` as the basic namespace to look up the the `useSubClass()` method in `Super`, but no information on that is actually compiled into code. In the resulting bytecode, the call is simply one directly to `Super.useSubClass()` and nothing more.

I sympathize with your plight, but Java is what it is. The closest thing you could come, I think, would be the following code:

```
public class Super {
    public static <T extends Super> void useSubClass(Class<T> sub) {
    }
}
```

And then call that method explicitly as either `Super.useSubClass(Sub1.class)` or `Super.useSubClass(Sub2.class)`.

Answer (score -2):

Although You can create a reference to the super class and point it  to any sub-class. This can also be done dynamically during run-time. This is a way of   **run-time polymorphism.**